# Iframe not displayed on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

I have a Javascript code which is making some calls to my API and then putting the result in an iframe. Everything is ok on Chrome and Safari.

But, on Firefox, the API call are correctly done and I have all the information needed. But, in the success function of my AJAX call, the head and body elements of my iframe are totally empty...

Here is a part of my code :

```
console.log($('#cop-widget').contents().find('head').html());
console.log($('#cop-widget').contents().find('body').html());
                
console.log(env, 'Getting consultation...');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: headers,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log($('#cop-widget').contents().find('head').html());
        console.log($('#cop-widget').contents().find('body').html());
                
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the output in my Firefox Console :

```
---
<meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://widget.cop.co/css/cop.css?v=1569320935042" crossorigin="anonymous"> sdk.js:1030:11
---
<div class="consultation"><div class="consultation-logged-in"></div><div class="consultation-header"></div><div class="propositions"></div><div class="proposition-send"></div><div class="consultation-footer"></div></div> sdk.js:1031:11
---
#12  Getting consultation...
---

---

---
```

Here is the output in my Google Chrome Console:

```
---
<meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://widget.cop.co/css/cop.css?v=1569320935042" crossorigin="anonymous"> sdk.js:1030:11
---
<div class="consultation"><div class="consultation-logged-in"></div><div class="consultation-header"></div><div class="propositions"></div><div class="proposition-send"></div><div class="consultation-footer"></div></div> sdk.js:1031:11
---
#12  Getting consultation...
---
<meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://widget.cop.co/css/cop.css?v=1569320935042" crossorigin="anonymous"> sdk.js:1030:11
---
<div class="consultation"><div class="consultation-logged-in"></div><div class="consultation-header"></div><div class="propositions"></div><div class="proposition-send"></div><div class="consultation-footer"></div></div> sdk.js:1031:11
---
```

How can we explain that difference?
I can't find anything on the web, and can't explain it...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: The domain is different, but my ajax call is correctly done and I can use the result variable in the success function (an it contains the correct data) : `Object { data: {…}, statusCode: 200, status: "success" }`

Comment: yes, but you cant modify contents of an iframe with a different domain usually. probably your browser prevents that from happening :) have a look at cors setup or the message api

Comment: No no no. My iframe is not calling an external URL. My JavaScript is calling my api and after, the JS is putting data in that iframe. And other calls are done before this one. And if it were a cors policy problem, Firefox would display it in the console.

Comment: hm, strange. i have made the experience that firefox is very picky about the ajax options. i dont have a clue though which setting exactly could be causing problems. maybe cache, auth, async or something

Comment: Anyone to help me? :-(

Comment: it looks a little bit like its not reproducable and/ or unclear what exactly isnt working. can you create a fiddle maybe?